# Update dictionary with a for loop so that the same key is inserted multiple times

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like update a dictionary items in a `for` loop. Here is what I have:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in range(0,5):
...      d.update({"result": i})
>>> d
{'result': 4}
```

But I want d to have following items:

```
{'result': 0,'result': 1,'result': 2,'result': 3,'result': 4}
```

Comment: dicts have to have unique keys, your idea simply won't work

Comment: Like EdChum said above, it wont work in a dictionary. For what reason do you want this to happen? There may be a better data structure for your needs?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole idea of dictionaries is that they have unique keys.
What you can do is have `'result'` as the key and a `list` as the value, then keep appending to the list.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in range(0,5):
...      d.setdefault('result', [])
...      d['result'].append(i)
>>> d
{'result': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Keys have to be unique in a dictionnary, so what you are trying to achieve is not possible. When you assign another item with the same key, you simply override the previous entry, hence the result you see.

Maybe this would be useful to you?

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in range(3):
...      d['result_' + str(i)] = i
>>> d
{'result_0': 0, 'result_1': 1, 'result_2': 2}
```

You can modify this to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have different values for the same key in your dictionary. One option would be to number the result:

```
d = {}
for i in range(0,5):
    result = 'result' + str(i)
    d[result] = i
d
>>> {'result0': 0, 'result1': 1, 'result4': 4, 'result2': 2, 'result3': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHA in dictionary the key cant be same :p in your example

```
{'result': 0,'result': 1,'result': 2,'result': 3,'result': 4}
```

you can use list of multiplw dict:

```
[{},{},{},{}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
d = {"key1": [8, 22, 38], "key2": [7, 3, 12], "key3": [5, 6, 71]}
print(d)

for key, value in d.items():
    value_new = [sum(value)]
    d.update({key: value_new})

print(d)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is over seven years old) with existing answers. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it improves upon what is already here. See [answer].

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> d = {"result": []}
>>> for i in range(0,5):
...     d["result"].append(i)
...    
>>> d
{'result': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code or expound on why this is the solution to the question.